# Create custom key binding for Atom editor snippet

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor, keymapping

I want to create a custom key binding for an Atom snippet. I've added the following snippet into my `snippets.cson` file (Atom → Open Your Snippets):

```
'.text.latex':
  'emph':
    'prefix': 'em'
    'body': '\\\\emph{$1}'
```

The snippet works just fine. Now I want to add a custom key command to my `keymap.cson` (Atom → Open Your Keymap), which triggers this snippet. I tried naive variations of the following addition, but so far none worked:

```
'atom-text-editor:not(.mini)':
  'cmd-i': 'latex:emph'
```

The [Atom Flight Manual keymaps section](https://atom.io/docs/latest/behind-atom-keymaps-in-depth) is not helpful for me regarding this problem.

Can someone help with the proper command?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard localization package might solve your problem. It allows you to generate an entirely custom keymap. https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization